# Which BlueTooth dongles are supported under Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I am trying to use a BlueTooth-based Apple keyboard under Ubuntu 9.04 and although the device is visible from the Bluetooth window, I cannot connect (or bond) to it. When prompted to type the actual 4-digit code, I always get the messabe "Connection failed". I want to connect the latest Apple Wireless keyboard (the Bluetooth-based one).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following site may be of some help:

http://hardware4linux.info/

Comment: The URL is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the bluetooth dongle is your problem but I use this [TrendNet](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156069) on Ubuntu 9.04 and it works fine.

Haven't used it with an Apple keyboard though.

Comment: Thank You ! I know about this brand name and I will get it from a local store soon. At this price, i think I can risk few more bucks to get this keyboard working.